# What is the probability that the first 2 cards are clubs, and the third card is a heart face card?

Tags: probability

> What is the probability that the first two cards are clubs, and the third card is a heart face card?

My attempt:

$$\frac{13 \cdot 12 \cdot 13}{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50}$$

Why is the final term that I have $3$, but not $13$?

Comment: A face card is a jack, queen, or king.  Hence, there are only three face cards in the heart suit.

Answer (score 1):

There are $12$ face cards $($$4$ of each since J,Q,K can be heart, club and spade$)$.

Therefore, there are $3$ total heart face cards in the entire deck.

Therefore the probability that the first $2$ are clubs and the third is a face card is $\dfrac{13}{52}\times\dfrac{12}{51}\times\dfrac{3}{50}=\dfrac{3}{850}$